# How to list LinkingObjects properties in Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I need to list all properties of type LinkingObjects of a object.

```
class Dogs: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var age: Int = 0
    dynamic var owner: Persons?
}


class Cats: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var age: Int = 0
    dynamic var owner: Persons?
}


class Persons: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var address: String = ""

    let dogs = LinkingObjects(fromType: Dogs.self, property: "owner")
    let cats = LinkingObjects(fromType: Cats.self, property: "owner")
}
```

ObjectSchema returns the schema correctly:

```
let person = Persons()
let schema = person.objectSchema
print(schema)
```

Result:

```
Persons {
 name {
    type = string;
    objectClassName = (null);
    linkOriginPropertyName = (null);
    indexed = NO;
    isPrimary = NO;
    optional = NO;
 }
 address {
    type = string;
    objectClassName = (null);
    linkOriginPropertyName = (null);
    indexed = NO;
    isPrimary = NO;
    optional = NO;
 }
 dogs {
    type = linking objects;
    objectClassName = Dogs;
    linkOriginPropertyName = owner;
    indexed = NO;
    isPrimary = NO;
    optional = NO;
 }
 cats {
    type = linking objects;
    objectClassName = Cats;
    linkOriginPropertyName = owner;
    indexed = NO;
    isPrimary = NO;
    optional = NO;
 }
}
```

However, objectSchema.properties does not return LinkingObjects properties.

```
let properties = schema.properties
print(properties)
```

Returns:

```
[name {
    type = string;
    objectClassName = (null);
    linkOriginPropertyName = (null);
    indexed = NO;
    isPrimary = NO;
    optional = NO;
}, address {
    type = string;
    objectClassName = (null);
    linkOriginPropertyName = (null);
    indexed = NO;
    isPrimary = NO;
    optional = NO;
}]
```

Where are the dogs and cats properties?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
let computedProperties = Persons.sharedSchema()?.computedProperties
```

Answer (score 0):

The LinkingObjects properties are listed in the `computedProperties` property of `RLMObjectSchema`, which is currently not public or present on the Swift version of the class. While it's possible to get to the private property given an instance of the obj-c class (via `.valueForKey("computedProperties")`), that won't work on the Swift ones and there isn't any good way to get to the obj-c `RLMObjectSchema` when using Realm Swift.

[There's an existing feature request to expose this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3562).